# how to create triggers function before insert show test message

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

i have a table

```
CREATE TABLE test.emp (
  empname text,
  salary integer,
  last_date timestamp,
  last_user text
);
```

and function

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.emp_stamp() RETURNS trigger AS $emp_stamp$
BEGIN
    -- Check that empname and salary are given
    IF NEW.empname IS NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'empname cannot be null';
    END IF;
    IF NEW.salary IS NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot have null salary', NEW.empname;
    END IF;

    -- Who works for us when she must pay for it?
    IF NEW.salary < 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot have a negative salary', NEW.empname;
    END IF;

    -- Remember who changed the payroll when
    NEW.last_date := current_timestamp;
    NEW.last_user := current_user;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

how to show message no need to update the values how can i modify my function

trigger is

```
CREATE TRIGGER emp_stamp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test.emp
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.emp_stamp();
```

Comment: What is your goal? Can you describe it little bit more?

Comment: In case of an update, the existing row is referenced with OLD

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is 1) make sure it's an update and not an insert (otherwise the reference to `old` won't make any sense and 2) compare to the existing record.  Since Employee name seems to be the PK and the last two fields are only to capture changes, my guess is you only want to test the salary:

```
-- Who works for us when she must pay for it?
IF NEW.salary < 0 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot have a negative salary', NEW.empname;
elsif TG_OP = 'UPDATE' and new.salary = old.salary then
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'salary is already %', NEW.salary;
END IF;
```

But of course you could also use this for any field.  If you wanted to make sure at least one changed, it would be something like this:

```
elsif TG_OP = 'UPDATE' and
   new.salary = old.salary and
   new.last_date = old.last_date and 
   new.last_user = old.last_user then
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Update does not alter any data';
END IF;
```